# Delimiter and Trigger Inquiry

Tags: mysql, triggers, delimiter

May I know what the following MySQL trigger does?

```
DELIMITER ??
CREATE TRIGGER before_results_update
BEFORE UPDATE ON Student_Results
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
INSERT INTO Result_Changes
SET ACTION = 'update',
ResultID = OLD.ID,
Result = OLD.Result,
User = USER(),
ChangedOn = NOW();
END ??
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DELIMITER creates a demarcation of the whole block. It uses `??` as the string if you will for the whole wrapper at the beginning and end. At the end, `;` is set as the DELIMITER that we are all used to typing for end-of-statement. DELIMITERS are not used in SQLFiddle or PHPMyAdmin, but they are on MySQL Workbench and others. So it is a client-side thing. Depends what you are using.

Before an actual UPDATE to table `Student_Results` it performs an INSERT (using a not-very used style of an insert stmt) to table `Result_Changes` specifying 5 column names.

The UPDATE has not technically occurred yet in `Student_Results`. But the trigger has access to the rows about to be updated there and they are referenced with the special "row name" called `OLD`.

The `FOR EACH ROW` could loop for 1 to N times.

Comment: Thank you for the clear explanation @Drew. Are there any faults that lies within the statement that can be prevented? Thank you

Comment: None that I can think of. If you run into any problems or stub out a schema and data load via SQLFiddle I would be happy to pound on it later.